# Flutter - How to get user's location using facebook sign in?

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

I can't get user's location using facebook sign in. I used `'user_location'` and graph API for getting the location but I can't seem to get the output. It only returns `null`. It would be great if you would help me..

This is my code:

```
void _signInFacebook() async {

FacebookLogin facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email', 'public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'user_location']);
final token = result.accessToken.token;
final graphResponse = await http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,birthday,location,email&access_token=${token}');
final profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);

var fb_ID = profile["id"];
var accessToken = token;

if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
  final credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: token);
  _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  // connecting to mongo database
  AuthService().facebookLogin(fb_ID, accessToken).then((val) {
    if (val.data['success']) {
      var token2 = val.data['token'];
      AuthService().getInfo(token2).then((val) async {  
          var store = val.data['user'];
        },
      );
    } else {
      print('WRONG EMAIL/ PASS');
      return;
    }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Graph API Explorer.

Comment: You're aware that this does not give you the user's "live" location - where are they at right now - but only the location they set in their profile, right? Does the user you are treting this with _have_ one set there?

Comment: @CBroe yes I'm aware of that and that's what I want to get. The location they set in their profile. But I am receiving null.

Comment: Did the user actually grant the permission? Did they even get _asked_ for it on the login dialog?

Comment: Yes the user was asked for birthday and city permission

Comment: And what is the visibility setting of the location on their profile? Public, only friends, ...?

Comment: the city / location is set public